# When executing resp := (HTTPRIO as iHttpCust).Customer(OrdNo) it fails with "Microsoft MSXML is not installed"

Tags: xml, soap, wsdl, delphi-10.3-rio

Running on a Windows 10-64bit, there is no MSXML to install. The latest MSXML is 6 and that is not updated since XP sp3. Trying to install it on Win 10 fails.

I'm redeveloping a Delphi 2007 program in Delphi 10.3.2 Rio. I have imported the WSDL file and added a HTTPRIO component, and have set it up in the same way as I did with the older version. I have created the necessary calls and compiled the program. When it runs and try to execute the (HTTPRIO as xxx) command, the fails with the message MSXML is not installed.

When skipping the call, and testing the rest of the program, loading an XML file with LoadFromFile, instead of LoadFromStream, the handling of the XML file is working fine. I'm using XMLParser.

AND more strange: When running the old (delphi 2007) program, which do exactly the same and in exactly the same way, on the same machine as the new program, it runs without failing.

The difference between the two is that I'm compiling the new program on a Win 10-64 machine, using Delphi 10.3.2 Rio, and of course with a newer version of the HTTPRIO component, whereas the old rogram was created on a Vista machine.

Obviously there is something I'm missing, but do not know what. Can anybody help ? Any help is very much appreciated.

Regards
Soren

Answer (score 0):

I have found a working solution. Using OmniXML instead.

Adding xml.xmldom and xml.omnixmldom to the uses clause, and then in formshow (or formcreate or anywhere in the code before the first XML call, add a line

DefaultDOMVendor := sOmniXmlVendor;

That's it. Gone is MSXML not installed error, and now I do get my soap response and have access to the webservice. NB! I did try using xml.win.msxmldom and to set defaultdomvender to SMSXML, but kept getting the not installed error.

I found the solution reading this page: https://delphiaball.co.uk/2014/12/29/setting-default-xml-dom-delphi-xe7/

Thanks to Google and Stephen Ball in this case.